# Word for someone unaware they are different or disabled

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word that describes someone who is unaware that they are different or disabled.For example, someone who can't smell but is unaware of what smelling is so they think they are the same as everyone else. What is this word?

Comment: *incognizant, innocent, insensible, mindless, misinformed, moronic, naive, nearsighted, neglectful, oblivious, thoughtless, unaware...* It's too open-ended.

Comment: This word does not mean stupid, or even ignorant. It is very specific.  Ignorant of their disability is what this word means.

Comment: Is there in fact anyone on the planet who's *"unaware of what smelling is"*? If you know exactly what concept you're after, could you not come up with a better example - one that might actually *have* a real-world referent for comparison?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT:

[***Anosognosia***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosognosia): a condition in which a person who suffers disability seems unaware of the existence of his or her disability.

or as previously suggested:

[***Oblivious***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/oblivious?region=us&q=oblivious): *not aware of or not concerned about what is happening around oneself*

Comment: It's more specific, like "oblivious that they have a disability"

Comment: Anosognosia, that is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: OED defines **anosognosia** as *unawareness of or **failure to acknowledge one's hemiplegia** or other disability* (Hemiplegia: injury to one side of the brain). I thought at first the question was too open-ended, but now it seems Too Localised!

Comment: @FumbleFingers A case of not being aware of one's own shortcomings, perhaps?

Comment: @Kris: I just mean *anosognosia* looks like a highly specialised medical term that's probably hopelessly inappropriate in any other contexts. If *oblivious* had been what OP was looking for, it would have been a reasonable question. But as it is, I just feel ELU is being used as a human-assisted medical dictionary lookup facility.